# How to build hmatrix with BLAS and LAPACK under Windows?

Tags: windows, haskell, lapack, blas, hmatrix

Windows 10 x64
Cabal 1.22

I'm following steps in Windows section https://github.com/AlbertoRuiz/hmatrix/blob/master/INSTALL.md

I downloaded hmatrix sources and gsl-lapack-windows.zip.
When I try to install hmatrix with:

> D:\Projects\workspace\hmatrix-0.16.1.5>cabal install
>   --extra-include-dirs=D:\Projects\workspace\gsl-lapack-windows\ --extra-lib-dirs=d:\Projects\workspace\gsl-lapack-windows\

I got this message that I'm still cannot solve:

> Configuring hmatrix-0.16.1.5... Failed to install hmatrix-0.16.1.5
>   Build log (
>   D:\Projects\workspace\hmatrix-0.16.1.5.cabal-sandbox\logs\hmatrix-0.16.1.5.log
>   ): Configuring hmatrix-0.16.1.5...
>   setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.4.0-x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.2.exe: Missing
>   dependencies on foreign libraries:
>   * Missing C libraries: blas, lapack, blas, lapack This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that provide these
>   libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries are
>   already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
>   flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where
>   they are. cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
>   hmatrix-0.16.1.5 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
>   ExitFailure 1

"-dev versions" I think is only for *nix based OSes. In folders I give to cabal there are blas.dll and lapack.dll.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I just ran into this problem as well. It seems we aren't the only ones. Did you have any luck fixing it? Also see: https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/issues/125

Comment: I have fixed a bit OpenBLAS cabal support. But there are still a compilation issues:
https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/pull/147

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Install mingw from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/, in my case `x86_64-posix-seh`). We need just `libgfortran-3.dll`, which is not present in ghc's mingw. Or you can get it from here: http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/libraries/VisualStudio/3.6.0/Dynamic-MINGW/Win64/libgfortran-3.dll (Replace Win64 with Win32 in url if necessary)
2. Get OpenBLAS binaries from https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/ (in my case `Win64-int32`).
3. Place `libopenblas.dll` and `libgfortran-3.dll` in some folder, in my case `C:\Programs\lib`
4. `cabal install hmatrix --flags=openblas --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Programs\lib`

That's all. You also have to pass libs to `ghci` (all libs must be in PATH, so in my case ghc's `mingw\bin` and `C:\Programs\lib` are in PATH):

`ghci -llibopenblas -llibgfortran-3 -llibgcc_s_seh-1`

where `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` is in ghc's mingw (in my case: `C:\Programs\ghc\ghc-8.0.1\mingw\bin`)

*NOTE: tested with ghc-8.0.1*
*UPDATE: i've found that now it can be done in less steps*

Comment: I'm getting `Missing C library: libopenblas` when running 6.

Comment: Ensure you have blas headers in your extra-include-dirs
In my case: 'd:\Programs\openblas\include' there's `cblas.h`, `f77blas.h` etc.

Comment: I do have the blas headers in the directory (for me, `C:/PF/openblas/include`, so I do `cabal install --flags=openblas --extra-lib-dirs=C:/PF/openblas/lib --extra-include-dirs=C:/PF/openblas/include`). I cloned OpenBLAS as in step 2 which has the blas headers in the include directory.

Comment: I've found some time to retry. Seems, that now it can be done in less steps with no need to build OpenBLAS and install hmatrix from sources. Hope this helps.