# Stack can't find libgfortran-3.dll when trying to build with hmatrix

Tags: haskell, dll, haskell-stack, hmatrix

I am trying to setup hmatrix on my Windows 10 machine with GHC 8.0.2.
I was following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423225/how-to-build-hmatrix-with-blas-and-lapack-under-windows) but when I try to build it says that it cannot find `libgfortran-3.dll` although I am sure I added it to the bin folder in the BLAS directory.
My code is in [here](https://github.com/yohad/networks)
I run `stack build` and this is what I get:

```
hmatrix-0.18.0.0: configure
Progress: 1/2
--  While building package hmatrix-0.18.0.0 using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab configure "--with-ghc=C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2\\bin\\ghc.EXE" "--with-ghc-pkg=C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2\\bin\\ghc-pkg.EXE" --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=C:\sr\snapshots\b201cfe6\pkgdb --package-db=D:\Haskell\networks\.stack-work\install\65995373\pkgdb --libdir=D:\Haskell\networks\.stack-work\install\65995373\lib --bindir=D:\Haskell\networks\.stack-work\install\65995373\bin --datadir=D:\Haskell\networks\.stack-work\install\65995373\share --libexecdir=D:\Haskell\networks\.stack-work\install\65995373\libexec --sysconfdir=D:\Haskell\networks\.stack-work\install\65995373\etc --docdir=D:\Haskell\networks\.stack-work\install\65995373\doc\hmatrix-0.18.0.0 --htmldir=D:\Haskell\networks\.stack-work\install\65995373\doc\hmatrix-0.18.0.0 --haddockdir=D:\Haskell\networks\.stack-work\install\65995373\doc\hmatrix-0.18.0.0 --dependency=array=array-0.5.1.1 --dependency=base=base-4.9.1.0 --dependency=binary=binary-0.8.3.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.1 --dependency=deepseq=deepseq-1.4.2.0 --dependency=random=random-1.1-9tceXaeYIMZ4JrKq20Egog --dependency=split=split-0.2.3.1-FWyXC6nhV0H3AfM8IzrEFk --dependency=storable-complex=storable-complex-0.2.2-G9QzpmZTKvgKKVagrcRWdL --dependency=vector=vector-0.11.0.0-HhutbadagxHIONIkSRJEug -fopenblas --extra-include-dirs=C:\OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-Win64-int32\include --extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\Yotam\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-Win64-int32\bin --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\Yotam\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: D:\Haskell\networks\.stack-work\logs\hmatrix-0.18.0.0.log

    Configuring hmatrix-0.18.0.0...
    Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign
    library:
    * Missing C library: libgfortran-3
    This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
    provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
    already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
    --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

D:\OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-Win64-int32\bin includes both `libopenblas.dll` and `libgfortran-3.dll` and the blas directory was taken from this [url](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.2.19/)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is that directory on your `PATH`?

Comment: No, but even when I add it to path the result is the same.

Comment: I know I shouldn't say this, but... are you sure you want to use _`hmatrix` on Windows_? I dislike both individually, for somewhat unrelated reasons (`hmatrix` for its ugly Matlab-like interface, Windows for its closedness), and `hmatrix`' GSL basis makes it an obvious fit for GNU/Linux based systems. Though it certainly _should_ work on Windows too (like Octave does), it'll definitely be a lot easier to use it on Linux or else use a native Haskell alternative which Stack actually has control over, on Windows. (_Or_ on Linux...) What kind of linear algebra is it you need to do?

Comment: Well I am trying to use hnn which requires hmatrix, I might switch to another package but now I just want to know what happened more than I want it to work. About Windows, I have only one machine and I don't trust myself to do dual boot correctly.

Comment: A possible other solution. It seems that we can remove the dependency on `libgfortran`, if we clone the package: https://gist.github.com/RyanGlScott/6a707536d6279e339909e43274ad66fc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to install it as follows.

In `yourpath\to\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512`, open a `msys2` shell by double-clicking on `msys2_shell.bat`.

In the shell, type:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

Then add these "extra" in `stack.yaml`:

```
extra-include-dirs:
- yourpath\to\OpenBLAS\include
extra-lib-dirs:
- yourpath\to\OpenBLAS\lib
- yourpath\to\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-msys\6.3.0
- yourpath\to\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\bin
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Is there by any chance an easier way to access the msys2 shell by default?

Comment: @YotamOhad No idea. I discovered that yesterday.

Comment: @YotamOhad Do you manage to install `hmatrix-gsl`? I can't find the C library `gsl-0`.

Comment: I did not encounter a problem with this library. I might have installed it implicitly but I am really unsure about it. You can look at my .cabal and stack.yaml configuration in my code (reference in the original question). What I have there currently works with `stack build`

Comment: @YotamOhad In fact you don't load this library.